# Prolog CLP order of operations?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Hi hopefully someone can help me. I was just wondering if my code below was sufficient in setting up a matrix of 12 x 12 and, assuming the 'constrain(M)' calls all the correct constraints which are defined in rules lower down, labelling each of the rows? It's failing at the moment and I've traced my constraints so I know they all work but didn't know whether it was because I'm calling them outside of the main predicate?

```
matrix(M) :-
M = [R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12],
R1 = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L],
R2 = [A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2],
R3 = [A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,K3,L3],
R4 = [A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4],
R5 = [A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5,L5],
R6 = [A6,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6,L6],
R7 = [A7,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7],
R8 = [A8,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8,J8,K8,L8],
R9 = [A9,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9,H9,I9,J9,K9,L9],
R10 = [A10,B10,C10,D10,E10,F10,G10,H10,I10,J10,K10,L10],
R11 = [A11,B11,C11,D11,E11,F11,G11,H11,I11,J11,K11,L11],
R12 = [A12,B12,C12,D12,E12,F12,G12,H12,I12,J12,K12,L12],

constrain(M),

labeling([],R1),
labeling([],R2),
labeling([],R3),
labeling([],R4),
labeling([],R5),
labeling([],R6),
labeling([],R7),
labeling([],R8),
labeling([],R9),
labeling([],R10),
labeling([],R11),
labeling([],R12).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always **separate** the constraint posting from the actual search (`labeling/2`).

The reason is clear: It can often be extremely expensive to search for concrete solutions. Posting the constraints, on the other hand, is often very fast.

If, as in your case, the two parts are uncleanly mixed, you cannot tell easily which part is responsible if there are unexpected problems such as nontermination.

In your case, the only thing you should improve in the main predicate is enforcing said separation between constraint posting and search.

The mistake that causes unexpected failure is most likely contained in one of the rules you did not post here. You can find out which rules are involved in the failure by systematically replacing the goals in which they are called by `true`. Thus, there's no need for tracing: You can debug CLP(FD) programs declaratively in this way.

**EDIT**: Here is more information about the separation between posting constraints and the search for concrete solutions. As introduced in [**GUPU**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/gupu/), we will use the notion of **core relation**, which has the following properties:

1. By convention, its name ends with an *underscore* `_`.
2. Also by convention, its last argument is the *list of variables* that need to be labeled.
3. It *posts* the CLP(FD) constraints. This is also called the (constraint) *modeling* part or (constraint) *model*.
4. It *doesn't* use `labeling/2`.

The search part is usually performed by `label/1` or `labeling/2`.

Suppose you have a predicate where you intermingle these two aspects, such as in your current case:

```
matrix(M) :-
        constraints_hold(M),
        ... relate M to variables Vs ...
        labeling(Strategy, Vs).
```

Obviously, for the reasons explained above, the call of `labeling/2` is the part we want to **remove** from this predicate. Of course, as you observe, we still want to somehow access the *variables* that are supposed to be labeled.

We do this as follows:

- We introduce a **new argument** to the core relation to pass around the list of  **finite domain variables** that need to be labeled.
- By convention, we reflect the additional argument by appending an **underscore** (`_`) to the predicate name.

So, we obtain the following core relation:

```
matrix_(M, Vs) :-
        constraints_hold(M),
        ... relate M to variables Vs ...
```

The only missing part (which you haven't done yet, but which you *should have done* in any case), is stating the relation between the object of interest (in this case: the *matrix*) and the finite domain variables. This is the part I leave as a simple exercise for you. Hint: `append/2`.

Once you have done all this, you can solve the whole task by combining the core relation and `labeling/2` in a single query or predicate:

```
?- matrix_(M, Vs), labeling(Strategy, Vs).
```

Note that this separation between core relation and search:

- makes it extremely easy to try different labeling strategies *without recompiling your program*.
- allows you to determine important procedural properties of the core relation *without needing to search for concrete solutions*.

Use the introduction and explanation of this important separation as an indicator when judging the quality of any text about CLP(FD) constraints.

Comment: Thank you - I understand separating them out is better but I'm not sure how to separate labeling from the domain. I've only been taught that variables, constraints and labeling goes in one predicate and while I understand how the matrix/constraints work this is the first time I've come across labeling and I don't find the library instructions very helpful!

Comment: I have added more information on how to separate these aspects. I hope it helps!

Comment: I have never come across the term "core relation" - is that your own terminology or does it come from the literature? I would normally call this the *(constraint) model*.

Comment: I took this from Ulrich Neumerkel's [**Teaching Prolog and CLP**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/tutorial.pdf) tutorial, presented 1997 in Leuven. In GUPU, this is called *Kernrelation* (German).

Comment: @mat, the document you cite does not contain the term. Whatever, I think you will be more widely understood by using the term **model** when talking about the declarative (mathematical/logical) representation of the application problem, as opposed to those parts of the CLP program that are concerned with the operational aspects of solving. In the context of constraint programming, the notion of a *core* is better reserved for certain subsets of the constraints (e.g. a "hard" sub-problem, a "minimal" subset without redundant constraints, etc).

Comment: Core relation in GUPU has a specific meaning: It is a relation that expresses the model *and* whose name ends with `_` *and* whose last argument is the list of variables that need to be labeled. For a long time, only the German word **Kernrelation** was used, the text I linked to shows traces of that. For the English translation, I would have actually preferred *kernel relation*, but Ulrich chose **core relation**, so that's what I have also adopted. I think that both translations fall a bit short of the German word, much like *Scheinlösung*, which has no known exact correspondence in English.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have added the model and modeling part terms to the description.